# How can I tell which workspace a directory is in?

Tags: perforce

I need to know which workspace the directory I am running the batch script is in, so I can get a list of files that are checked out in that workspace.
Is there an easy way to do this?

I am hoping I don't need to get a list of all workspaces and then manually go through them trying to figure out which one my current directory is a child of.

I am doing this on Windows.

Comment: can you run `p4 info` in your directory? The client name is the workplace name.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your client is set by your P4CLIENT definition or the '-c' argument, not by your current directory. Your current directory might, however, influence the choice of a P4CONFIG file with client-side settings. Try 'p4 set' to see your client-side configuration settings.

Comment: Sadly I have many perforce workspaces, so it will typically not be the 'active' workspace that I need.